# Image not appearing in HTML page

Tags: html

Is there a problem with my HTML code that would cause my image to not appear?

```
<tbody>
       <tr>
   <td>1517 N Lotus</td>
      <td><img src = "0004livingroombrown.jpeg" alt ="livingroom" width="92"height="120"></td>
         <td>hello3</td>
         <td>hello4</td>
         <td>hello5</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Comment: your image is in the same folder as your html?

Comment: If you are sure the path to the image file is correct, do you have a link to a site where it goes wrong? (I do not see any error in the html.)

Comment: Your HTML is fine, it's hard to explain anything.  Make sure your file name/path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

your code doesn't show any problem.

 If you are sure that the image is on the same folder where code exist
than try to change the extension .jpeg to .jpg

 that will resolve your problem.